# Delaying an action inside a function

Tags: millis

My current function is supposed to play a sound effect, then after the sound effect is done (14 seconds), perform the next action (`digitalWrite(CONTROLLINO_R1, LOW)`).

```
if (digitalRead(CONTROLLINO_A8) == HIGH && !skeleLatch) {
  skeleLatch = 1;
  wTrig.trackPlayPoly(2);
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if((currentMillis-previousMillis) >= 14000) {
    digitalWrite(CONTROLLINO_R1, LOW);
    previousMillis = millis();
  }
}
```

As it is, it performs both at the same time. I do not know how to correctly implement the delay so that it waits.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If your program shall not do anything during 14 seconds, why not simply use `delay()`?

Comment: its going into an escape room - meaning, there is a good chance someone else might activate something else while that music is playing.  In the off chance, i'd like to be sure it doesn't interfere with any other inputs

Comment: You can get the current time (milliseconds since startup) using `millis()`. Using that you can tell whether it's been 14 seconds since a particular event.  Does that give enough of a clue?

Comment: Where do you set up `previousMillis` (apart from *after* the decision in the code you posted)?

Comment: previousMillis was set to 0 unsigned long outside loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  unsigned long triggerMillis = 0;

  if (digitalRead(CONTROLLINO_A8) == HIGH && !skeleLatch)
  {
    skeleLatch = 1;
    wTrig.trackPlayPoly(2);
    triggerMillis = millis();
  }

  if (millis() - triggerMillis >=14000 && skeleLatch)
  {
    digitalWrite(CONTROLLINO_R1, LOW);
    skeleLatch = 0;
  }
```

This should work, depending on how long your CONTROLLINO_A8 is staying high you might want to invest some more time to set up an interrupt on that pin, to make sure you don't miss a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If your code does not need to be re-entrant (work within a multitasking environment), the simpler solution is [Arduino's delay function](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Delay), designed specifically for waiting a specific number of milliseconds.

```
delay(14000)
```